# web2py: multiple forms in a view

Tags: python, web2py

```
def test():

    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s')))
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('evo', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_evo.id', '%(evo_type)s', orderby=db.tbl_evo.id)))

return dict(form=form)
```

I want to be able to have multiple SQLFORMS in a single view. How would I do this from one controller function?

For my benefit, how would I call different functions (not named test()) to generate forms in the same view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code doesn't process the forms, so you would need to call the `.process()` method on each form. When you do that, you can specify a unique name for each form, which will enable web2py to tell them apart when submitted:

```
form1 = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards',
    requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s')))
form1.process(formname='form1')
```

If you want to call separate functions to generate and process each form, you can put those functions in a model file or module and then call them from the test.html view. If you want to use AJAX, a better option is to put each form inside a [component](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12#Components) using `LOAD()`:

```
{{=LOAD('default', 'myform1', ajax=True)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the manual, specifically:

[Forms & Validators: Multiple forms per page](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#Multiple-forms-per-page)